# get daily view of a given video - YouTube Api V3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to get the daily view of a given video.

For example, I have a YouTube video ID, Then I need to retrieve its channel id, Then I need to get the daily viewcoun of that video.

My problem is that I can only get information about my channel (Logged in user's channel). I can not see the results for other users at all. It says it is "forbidden"

Ps. I used both google.api.explorer and a python code. (the authentication is OK.)

Does anyone know how to get these info?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your program twice such that 00:00 Monday and 00:00 Tuesday, you can get daily viewCount of the video since you are able to get statistics of a single video. However, if you want to find dailyViewCount of a video, I think you would not able to do it. You can follow my way in unix by crontab in order to run in every 24 hours and get result and use it later to subtriction

Comment: So what is the point of google api v3? My question is how can I access others' videos? (not only mine)

Answer (score 0):

Due to privacy issues, you can only access to your own videos (or the videos uploaded by channels you manage) statistics.

For other videos, you can get basic numbers like viewcounts etc but not in detail.

Comment: I don't understand. Somewhere it says the statistics is for self uploaded like "Total viewcounts (and more) for all self-uploaded content". And some other places it says nothing.

Comment: You just said "For other videos, you can get basic numbers like viewcounts etc but not in detail." But how to access this? Any reference available?